# How to create onClick function for a dynamically generated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, dynamically-generated

I am trying to implement onClick function for a div which is getting generated depending on some validations while submitting the page. I am trying to implement the same from an external js file.

HTML design is something like :

```
<div id="QViewInfo" style="top: 207px; left: 531.5px;">
    //dynamically generated
    <div>
    ---
    ----
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I am trying to implement the onClick function like below :

```
$('img.popUpClose.popUpCloseQview').each(function (index) {
    $(this).on("click", function (e) {
        //DO something
    });
});
```

But the issue is, this $('img.popUpClose.popUpCloseQview') element is not there in the code on the first time. After the submit button click valiations are happening and depending on the condition this pop up message is coming up and this function is not working anytime.

Tried some other options too. But none of these are working.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Aniket

Comment: [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Normal state <div id="QViewInfo"></div>

If the validation fails, then below data got added. Now I was trying to implement the onClick function for $('img.popUpClose.popUpCloseQview').

<div id="QViewInfo">
 <div class="oosInfo">
  <div class="alertImgDiv">
   <span class="oosAlertImg"></span>
  </div>
   <img src="/Images/...." onclick="QView.close();" alt="Close Quick View" class="popUpClose popUpCloseQview">
   <div>other details</div>
 </div>
</div>

Below code didnt worked even,

$('#QViewInfo').on('click', 'img.popUpClose.popUpCloseQview', function(){
    alert("A");
})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are dynamically generating the div in jquery, you can add the click event then. For example:

```
var div = $("<div>");
div.click(function(){//dostuff});

$("#QViewInfo").append(div);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could attach the click event to all the `div`'s of element `#QViewInfo` using event delegation **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** like :

```
$('#QViewInfo').on('click', 'div', function(){
    //DO something
})
```

**NOTE :** No need for using `each()` loop.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#QViewInfo').append('<div>Div 3</div>');

$('#QViewInfo').on('click', 'div', function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="QViewInfo" style="top: 207px; left: 531.5px;">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
</div>
```

**Working snippet with comment code :**

```js
var img = '<img src="/Images/...." onclick="alert(\'QView.close();\')" alt="Close Quick View" class="popUpClose popUpCloseQview">';

$('.oosInfo').append(img);

$('#QViewInfo').on('click', 'img.popUpClose.popUpCloseQview', function(){ 
  alert("A"); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="QViewInfo"> 
  <div class="oosInfo"> 
    <div class="alertImgDiv"> 
      <span class="oosAlertImg"></span> 
    </div> 
    
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Normal State - 
<div id="QViewInfo"></div>

If the validation fails, then below html added. Now I was trying to implement the onClick function for $('img.popUpClose.popUpCloseQview').

<div id="QViewInfo">
 <div class="oosInfo">
  <div class="alertImgDiv">
   <span class="oosAlertImg"></span>
  </div>
   <img src="/Images/...." onclick="QView.close();" alt="Close Quick View" class="popUpClose popUpCloseQview">
   <div>other details</div>
 </div>
</div>

Below code didnt worked even,

$('#QViewInfo').on('click', 'img.popUpClose.popUpCloseQview', function(){
    alert("A");
})

Comment: (NOTE that you've already another click event attached `onClick`) the code should work if you `QView.close();` not fail.. check the new snippet in my answer.